# Which is correct: "Real Madrid compete very well," or "Real Madrid competes very well?"

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, british-english

I think there's a difference in the ways in which sports announcers from the U.S. and U.K. refer to the teams. If my memory serves me correctly, I think announcers in FIFA from the U.K. will use forms of verbs corresponding to a singular noun; in the U.S., I believe it's the reverse. Please, correct me if I'm wrong about the two different styles across countries, but I think my question's clear enough.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Speakers of BrE refer to groups of a certain size in the plural, whereas AmE treats all corporate entities as a unified whole, as a single (conceptual) person. I'm a native AmE speaker, so I'm not sure what the rules or heuristics for the British *corporate are* are, but I know while they refer to e.g., Morgan Stanley in the plural, the (UK) government is always referred to in the singular. Perhaps one of our resident BrE speakers can shed more light.

Comment: This _is_ a duplicate. You could check at '[collective nouns ...](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=collective+noun+agreement) while I find a better match.'

Comment: *Real Madrid compete real well.* Sorry.

Comment: @Dan Bron I think that is very misleading. Most Brits I know / have corresponded with about this use notional concord: Real Madrid was founded in 1902 / Real Madrid are not playing as well as Brucilona.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, I'm very unclear on the details. What are the rules for "notional concord"?

Comment: @Dan Bron See Robert Grant's answer here at (not really to!) ['Why do Americans add the in front of a team name but the British do not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154057/why-do-americans-add-the-in-front-of-a-team-name-but-the-british-do-not/154322#154322)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, though you're right it lacks a "*to*" (i.e. a rationale which would help me understand in which cases BrE uses the plural and which the singular). Robert also says BrE uses *notional agreement*, but without describing what these "notions" are that's a bit of a tautology: clearly AmE and BrE speakers *conceive* of corporate bodies differently, and saying BrE "agrees better notionally with real life" is a bit ", um, parochial.

Comment: I've written more [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69650/subject-verb-agreement-two-schools-of-thought/69693#69693).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Now *that's* a much better answer. +1!

Answer (score 0):

> Real Madrid **competes** very well.

I believe that "competes" is the proper verb for the sentence mainly because of the subject verb agreement regardless of the adverb "very well"

Comment: But that wasn't the question OP asked.

Comment: It could be either "competes" or "compete," depending on regional differences in conjugating verbs after collective nouns.