# England is/are playing?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I have this doubt when it comes to sports and teams. 
Is it England is playing or England are playing?
Similarly, is it "Arsenal is playing..." or "Arsenal are playing..."?

Comment: In Britain, with sports teams it is always *are*, England *are*, Arsenal *are*. Best let Americans speak for themselves, but I hear them saying *is* in many instances where we say *are*.

Comment: See this answer by a [BrEng speaker, WS2](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/138823/44619) *This may not be the case in America where sports teams are always singular. 'Our team is winning'. But* **in Britain sports teams are always plural.** *‘Arsenal are currently top of the Premier League’. 'The England cricket team are currently playing Australia in an Ashes series'. India are currently the undisputed leaders in world cricket.*

Comment: and see [this post](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/154156/44619) which (indirectly) answers your question: *"Arsenal" is the name of the football club, the club is considered a single thing that exists independently to the collection of players, staff, etc.

But people will often refer to "the gunners", in reference to the current Arsenal players of the team when they want to talk about the collection of players.*

Comment: And the same WS2 cited above: [The Gunners(Arsenal) are second in the table to the Pensioners (Chelsea). The Magpies (Newcastle) have a slight edge on the Saints (Southampton).](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/154072/44619)