# why is "go missing" in this sentence ?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> Napoli go missing against Juventus as Higuaín seals a victory for 'Maxism'

This sentence is the title of [this article](https://www.theguardian.com/football/blog/2017/dec/02/napoli-go-missing-against-juventus-as-higuain-seals-a-victory-for-maxism). I really don't understand why " **go missing**" is used instead of " **goes missing**".

Comment: It’s referring to Napoli as a plural collection of team members.

Comment: And it's a UK/US thing whether teams with a singular spelling are regarded as singular or plural.

Comment: Note   in this title http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-11-06/manchester-city-beat-arsenal-to-extend-premier-league-lead/9121376  they use "Manchester City beats Arsenal "  and for native speaker like you if they write "Manchester City beat Arsenal", is there any difference between them ?

Comment: It's sports - a language of its own. In the US we switch nimbly between obvious singulars and plurals: *The Red Sox beat the Yankees,"* but *"St. Joseph beats Holy Family"*.  We choke on something ambiguously novel like *The Miami Heat*, which either *suck* or *sucks.*. ;-)

Comment: Answered at [England is or are playing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277398/england-is-are-playing), itself claimed to be a duplicate of [Are collective nouns always plural or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular).

Comment: Note that _beat_ is potentially confusing because of its irregular simple past form: _he **beats** them_ (present) vs. _he **beat** them_ (simple past) vs. _they **beat** him_ (present) vs. _they **beat** him_ (simple past).

Answer (score 0):

Napoli is a plural as its referring to a group of team members therefore it should be go not goes.

Comment: That's for people subscribing to notional concord here. Not all would do.