# "Australia 'has' defeated India in the World Cup" vs "Australia 'have' defeated India in the World Cup"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, have

Here, 'Australia' refers to the Australian team, and not just the country.

I have read in a book that 'have' is to be used in case of a team name if it's of a country.

So which is correct? Which form do you use when referring to teams?

> Australia **has** defeated India in the World Cup.

> Australia **have** defeated India in the World Cup.

Comment: In UK English, "have".  In US English, "has".  Other such questions may be found in this forum, so this may be marked as a duplicate...  It is not just country hame: Similar for any organization with multiple people within.

Comment: Are asking about which is correct in Indian English?

Comment: No, not particular to Indian English. I just wanted to know why 'have' is being used if Australia or the Australian team is a singular entity?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are collective nouns (and in particular companies) always given a plural verb form, or are certain ones treated as singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-and-in-particular-companies-always-given-a-plural-verb-fo) See also [England **is** or **are** playing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/277398/england-is-are-playing)